# Why does this Python code not print anything

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering, why does this Python code not print anything in my console?

```
from time import sleep
while True:
    print('#', end='')
    sleep(1)
```

If I remove the `sleep` function it works, and if I remove the `end=''` part it works too. I am using Python 3.9 and I have tested this with Dash, Bash and ZSH. I can achieve the desired output with the following code.

```
from time import sleep
hash = '#'
while True:
    print('\r' + hash, end='')
    hash = hash + '#'
    sleep(1)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The above-mentioned code is printing as it is

Comment: I just checked your code and it works well can you specify your problem again ?

Comment: @AtaReenes nothing is showing on standard output until I interrupt the script from running. I already received a working answer, though.

Comment: its interesting which compiler or IDE are you using currently ?

Comment: @AtaReenes I'm just running a script from the terminal, using the Python 3.9 interpreter.

Comment: as  kwkt mentioned it's due to buffering many compilers solve that buzz by themselves that's why we normally dont cross with this bug . But yes for IDE flush=True can solve your problem.

Comment: If you remove the `sleep`, it works the same way as before, but you see the output because the output buffers are flushed on program exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume it's due to buffering. Try adding `flush=True` as one of the optional parameter to `print`.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I will mark this as the answer as soon as it lets me do so.

Comment: IMHO It would be nice if `flush=True` was automatically enabled when `end=...` is specified. (I understand that there is zero chance for such a change).

Comment: @VPfB There's multiple ways you can go for that. 1, you can run Python with flag `-u` and it'll go unbuffered. 2, you can change the file descriptor `sys.stdout` to not buffer. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/2327379 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

When using `print`, a newline character is added to your string unless you're overriding it (as you do) with the `end` parameter. For performance reasons, there exists an I/O buffer that only prints when it encounters a newline or the buffer fills up. Since your string doesn't contain a newline character anymore, you have to manually flush the buffer (i.e. send it to be printed).

```
from time import sleep
hash = '#'
while True:
    print('\r' + hash, end='', flush=True)
    hash = hash + '#'
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: @RayBern Sorry, I was wrong in my earlier comment. It seems to be that the buffer flush at the `\r` as well.